# how to allow the same username but different company registration?

Tags: meteor, account

in Meteor, how to allow the same username but different company registration?

i want to set username with unique: false
how to custom Accounts package?

```
accounts_server.js
users._ensureIndex('username', { unique: true, sparse: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

Having a unique username across your system has strong reasons, especially integrity and validation. Circumventing this functionality can lead to potential risks and may undermine the stability of the `accounts` packages as they are built around the assumption, that users are unique by `username` or `email`.

You can see that in the [source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L1125), where `Accounts.createUser` is checking for unique usernames and emails, independently from the raw Mongo collection.

If you still insist to override this behavior (which I highly suggest to not to), you need to do everything manually (validation not included here):

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'

const createUser = ({ username, password, company }) => {
  if (Meteor.users.find({ username, company }).count() > 0) {
    throw new Error(`Account already exists for ${username}@${company}`)
  }

  const userId = Meteor.users.insert({ username, company })
  Accounts.setPassword(userId, password)
  return userId
}

Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.users.rawCollection().dropIndex('username_1')
  Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
    createUser({ username: 'johndoe', password: 'password', company: 'Software Inc.' })
    createUser({ username: 'johndoe', password: 'password', company: 'Pro Software' })
  }, 1000)
})
```

by doing so you need to override all Accounts methods (especially authentication and login) with your own implementation. However, as I said - **better don't do it.**

**Better solution: Use Email instead**

The combination of **username** and **company name** is already incorporated in the **email** pattern.

The easiest solution would therefore be to implement accounts based on `email`, rather than on the `username`:

```js
const createUser = (email, password, company) => {
  const userId = Accounts.createUser({ email, password })
  Meteor.users.update(userId, { $set: { company }})
  return userId
}
```

Comment: Thank you pro! i will be try your solution and i will feedback the result to you later.

Comment: I used the method to concat username=username+"_workspacename"; and then replace "_workspacename" by blank before display.